# How to send a mail using Outlook template using Python?

Tags: python, email, automation

I had created an Outlook template. Now I have to send that mail to many users. want to prepare a script that will fetch the CSV file which includes emails list and send it to them.

Outlook Template contains Coloured fonts and underlined text with multiple font sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `smtplib` that comes with python. Note that this will require your email account allows smtp, which is not necessarily enabled by default.

```
SERVER = "smtp.example.com"
FROM = "yourEmail@example.com"
TO = ["listOfEmails"] # must be a list

SUBJECT = "Subject"
TEXT = "Your Text"

# Prepare actual message
message = """From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

**EDIT**: this example uses reserved domains like described in RFC2606

```
SERVER = "smtp.example.com"
FROM = "johnDoe@example.com"
TO = ["JaneDoe@example.com"] # must be a list

SUBJECT = "Hello!"
TEXT = "This is a test of emailing through smtp of example.com."

# Prepare actual message
message = """From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.login("MrDoe", "PASSWORD")
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at the library [yagmail](https://pypi.org/project/yagmail/).

From the top of the page:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP()
contents = [
    "This is the body, and here is just text http://somedomain/image.png",
    "You can find an audio file attached.", '/local/path/to/song.mp3'
]
yag.send('to@someone.com', 'subject', contents)

# Alternatively, with a simple one-liner:
yagmail.SMTP('mygmailusername').send('to@someone.com', 'subject', contents)
```

When it comes to coloring and font changes - you'll have to use HTML for that. Define a body in a separate string and pass that into contents.